# SWI-Prolog family tree parent_of/2

Tags: prolog

```
male(jerry).
male(stuart).
male(warren).
male(peter).

female(kather).
female(maryalice).
female(ann).

brother(jerry,stuart).
brother(jerry,kather).
brother(peter, warren).

sister(ann, maryalice).
sister(kather,jerry).

parent_of(warren,jerry).
parent_of(maryalice,jerry).
```

I was given the facts above and I need to define a rule using the predicate ***parent_of***. Yes, it is the same predicate as the above facts defined by parent_of.

Assume I have a `sibling(X, Y)` rule that will return all the correct sibling pairs.

I write my `parent_of(X, Y)` rule as `parent_of(X, Y) :- parent_of(X, A), sibling(A, Y).`

However, this implementation will lead me to an infinity loop.

Is there a way to define the rule `parent_of(X, Y)` such that it will return

```
(warren, jerry), 
(warren, stuart), 
(warren, kather), 
(maryalice, jerry), 
(maryalice, stuart), 
(maryalice, kather)
```

I also tried

```
parent_of(X, Y) :- 
    parent_of(X, jerry), 
    brother(jerry, Y).
```

I can get the correct answers by this way but it ended up in "Out of local stack" error. Besides that, I don't think the rule is fine as I hard coded it.

I have seen suggestions like change the rule name to something else such as `another_parent_of(X, Y)`. It does solve the problem, but it is a requirement for me to define it using the same predicate.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDITED**

The intention of this exercise is to write rules such that you can complete this family tree, though only minimal facts are given. As you can see, it only states that Warren is the father of Jerry, and from brother and sister facts, we know Jerry is the brother of Stuart and Kather. So I will have a rule, `parent_of(X, Y)` to deduce Warren is also the father of Stuart and Kather, though this was not stated in the facts above.

The main concern is how can I write my `parent_of(X, Y)` rule to avoid it getting into infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you need to use `parent_of` in the definition of `sibling`. Why you no just write:

```
sibling(X, Y) :-
    parent_of(Parent, X),
    parent_of(Parent, Y).
```

I also don't understand the logic of the facts that you are given. You have `male` and `female`, but you also have `brother` and `sister`; why not define `brother` and `sister` in terms of "brother is a male sibling" and "sister is a female sibling"? I already show above how to define "siblings have same parent".

Anyway, this is really old tired question, it is very amazing how many times "Prolog family tree" has been regurgitated.

```
the cow the old cow she is dead
it sleeps well the horned head
we poor lads tis our turn now
to hear such tunes as killed the cow
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Let's reduce it to simpler version of my question. I am only given the fact that Warren is the father of Jerry, then I have to write a rule to deduce the fact Warren is also the father of Stuart and Kather. You may ignore this sibling(X, Y) rule and substitute with brother  and sister facts. The main concern is how can I write my parent_of(X, Y) rule to avoid infinity loop.

Comment: @Da_Pz you should always aim to reduce to the simplest version of any question, otherwise you just confuse random strangers who want to help but have to guess what you ask.

Comment: @Da_Pz now after I write an answer maybe it is to the wrong question.... Y U no simplify your question in the question first (not in comment to answer to wrong question) and then maybe I try to answer?

Comment: @Da_Pz Just a short comment because children come out of mothers not fathers (even though father also put half the child in mother) maybe it is better to have fact that state who is mother not who is father? Or maybe not.

Comment: Hi @User9213, yeah we can always write rules like _father(X, Y)_ and _mother(X, Y)_, but only based on the facts that we are given. However, I don't think it is helpful in defining my _parent_of(X, Y)_ rule. As to find out who is the father/mother of a child, we definitely have to use the predicate _parent_of_. If you want to define _parent_of(X, Y)_ as (_father(X, A)_ ; _mother(X,A)_), _sibling(A, Y)_, the call of _father_ or _mother_ predicates will call again _parent_of_, and thus goes into infinite loop.

Comment: @Da_Pz The problem with your current collection of "facts" is that it looks like a puzzle not like a family tree. So I struggle to understand the intention of completing this task, what is the thing that you should learn by completing it?

Comment: Alright let me explain for you. The intention of this exercise is to write rules such that you can complete this family tree, though only minimal facts are given. As you can see, it only states Warren is the father of Jerry, and from brother and sister facts, we know Jerry is the brother of Stuart and Kather. So I will have a rule, _parent_of_, to deduce Warren is also the father of Stuart and Kather, though this was not stated in facts. Am I clear enough? I may not expressing it well after spending hours of figuring how to do this.

Comment: @Da_Pz Ok, I see, so it is a puzzle that you have to solve under artificial limitations. I try to see if I can find answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a way to directly solve your problem. But if your Prolog offers [tabling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Tabling), here is an easy way:

`:- use_module(library(tabling)).
...
:- table parent_of/2.
parent_of(warren,jerry).
parent_of(maryalice,jerry).
parent_of(X, Y) :- parent_of(X, A), sibling(A, Y).
...
?- parent_of(X,Y).
X = warren,
Y = stuart ;
X = warren,
Y = jerry ;
X = warren,
Y = kather ;
X = maryalice,
Y = stuart ;
X = maryalice,
Y = jerry ;
X = maryalice,
Y = kather.`